# Как получить аргументы с которыми запущен сторонний процесс | Golang

Tags: golang

Есть процесс, допустим test.exe, он запущен с аргументами --argument1 --argument2 и их видно через диспетчер задач.
Вопрос: Как получить эти аргументы через golang?

Comment: получить как? где? что в результате должно получиться?

Answer (score 0):

нужно получить список процессов, найти нужный процесс и у него глянуть команндную строку с которой он был запущен. Вот пример использующий либу которая умеет это делать

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/process"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    processes, _ := process.Processes()
    for _, process := range processes {
        name, _ := process.Name()
        // замени busybox на имя программы
        if strings.Contains(name, "busybox") {
            fmt.Println(process.Cmdline())
        }
    }
}
```